# What is the password format supported by rar?

Tags: rar, rarcrack

What is the password format supported by rar?

More specifically, [rarcrack](http://rarcrack.sourceforge.net/) has a default character set for searching for the password of an encrypted rar file.

```
0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Can an encrypted rar file has a password with characters not in the above set?

Is there a maxium password length which rar supports?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> RAR maximum file encryption password length is 127 characters. Longer
>   passwords are truncated to this length.

Source : https://www.win-rar.com/enc_faq.html

> v5.0 - supported by WinRAR 5.0 and later. Changes in this version:
>   Optional AES encryption increased from 128-bit to 256-bit.

Source : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAR_(file_format)

It can contain special characters.

Comment: Thanks. It seems virtually impossible for rarcrack  to crack an encrypted rar file, correct?

Comment: It depends of the password strength.

Comment: Is the bit number of AES encryption related to the max password length?

Comment: "128-bit encryption" means that the secret key is a sequence of 128 bits. It tells nothing about the password length or contents. There are 2^128 = 340282366920938463463374607431768211456 possible keys of 128 bits. Source : https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/31726/why-so-long-to-break-128-bit-encryption

Comment: See also (Password strength) : https://xkcd.com/936/ and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_strength